# How to determine if a multi-dimensional vector comes from a multi-variate distribution or not?

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-distribution

I have a complex multivariate distribution given by a multivariate random number generator (black box). In other words, whenever I call the "generator" I get a random vector containing numeric components which are correlated (or even related in a more complex than linear way).

I also have a special vector and I want to know if this vector could be generated by the generator with a reasonable "probability". In other words, I would like to know if this "special vector" is an outlier or it is total "normal" vector and could be generated by the generator.

I would like to emphasise that I have many dimension (around 50 or 100).

Comment: It sounds like you want some kind of generalization of Mahalanobis distance. What do you know about the random vector generator? If you can’t say anything about it’s distribution, either by knowing the distribution or taking values from it until you can characterize it decently, then I think this task is impossible. (I don’t see why you would be unable to simulate thousands or millions (billions...) of draws from your random vector generator, though.)